# How to evaluate a recurrent connection in an artificial neural network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

I just can't understand how should I compute the output of a neural network, which contains a recurrent connection.

So here is an example:

> [image: http://i.imgur.com/XdXupIj.png]

*(i_1,2 are the input values, w_1,2,3,r are the connection weights, and o_1 is the output value.)*

For the sake of simplicity, let's say that there are no activation or transfer functions.
If I understand the workings of ANNs correctly, then in case of not taking the red recurrent connection into consideration, the output is calculated as

```
o_1=(w_1*i_1+w_2*i_2)*w_3
```

However, what is the case when the red connection is taken into account? Would it be

```
o_1=((w_1*i_1+w_2*i_2)+(w_1*i_1+w_2*i_2)*w_r)*w_3
```

maybe? But that's just my guess.